# Filter for landscape format images in views

Tags: 7, views, media

I am working with Views 3 and Drupal 7 and created a view to display a list of images from a given content type in a slideshow. For layout reasons, images in portrait format don't work. Is there any way to filter for "width > height"?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution
in given content type, add a CCK (select list) field having  option "width > height". select this field when the image is landscape. then in views add this filter too. 
 by doing this, only images that are "width > height" will be shown

Comment: thanks for your reply. this would be a solution i am not really happy with. someone would need to go through all the existing content and select this field.
it is possible to select a filter for given widths or heights in views. i just thought i've missed the part where you can have the filter working for both fields, since the values are already stored in the database if you upload an image.